# Traceur - this returns undefined inside a super class method

Tags: javascript, oop, ecmascript-6, traceur

I have a class `EditNote` which inherits from `ViewNote`, the problem is that whenever i try accessing `super.removeElement('bible-close')` ( which is a method in the super class ) i get a `TypeError` (`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined`)

```
class ViewNote {
    constructor() {
        let viewNote = document.querySelector('.view-note');
        let viewNoteParent = document.querySelector('.bible-view-note-list');

        this.viewNote = () => viewNote;
        this.viewNoteParent = () => viewNoteParent;
    }
    removeParentElement(el) {

       this.viewNote().removeAttribute('style');

       Array.from(
           this.viewNote().querySelectorAll('.bible-view-note-item'),
           el => el.remove()
       );

    }

}

class EditNote extends ViewNote {

    constructor() {
        super();


        super.showNote({
            editwidget: true,
            listener({content, title, creationDate}, ...args) {
                for (let i of args) {
                    i.addEventListener('click', e => {
                        let target = e.target;

                        if (target.className.includes('bible-close')) {
                            super.removeElement('bible-close');
                            return ;
                        }

                    })
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The problem with the above code is that `super.removeParentElement('bible-close');` throws a `TypeError`. I even tried using the `this` keyword but it did not work because `this` is undefined inside the `super.showNote` method

Comment: Well, the method is named `removeParentElement` not `removeElement`?

Comment: Also, `super` in your method declaration refers to the parent of the *object literal* (which `this` refers to), not the super class prototype. Make `listener` an arrow function as well

Comment: Thanks @Bergi . It works now :D